# Insert character into string, then split into array SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to turn this

| id | lineup |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | DST Ravens WR Odell Beckham Jr. WR DeSean Jackson |
| 02 | DST 49ers QB Lamar Jackson WR Sammy Watkins |

Into this

| id | lineup |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | #DST Ravens #WR Odell Beckham Jr. #WR DeSean Jackson |
| 02 | #DST 49ers #QB Lamar Jackson #WR Sammy Watkins |

then run this code

```
SELECT
  id,
  unnest(string_to_array(lineup, '#')) AS picks
FROM table;
```

To get this

| id | picks |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | DST Ravens |
| 01 | WR Odell Beckham Jr. |
| 01 | WR Desean Jackson |
| 02 | DST 49ers |
| 02 | QB Lamar Jackson |
| 02 | WR Sammy Watkins |

Any advice on putting # symbols to the left of specific words in a string?
Also, can anyone confirm if the string to array code will work as intended?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you don't accept answers, I'll add a potential solution as a comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61a225d47089e415982de4c46be1d490

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  That is indeed the solution.  Also, I'm new to the community.  Did I miscategorize this post?  Unsure why answers can't be submitted for this one

Comment: Your question was good. The previous questions you have asked has answers but you haven't accepted them. You can accept answers by clicking on the check mark besides an answer of your choice. Some users on StackOverflow don't mark any answer as accepted, and that's OK too. My personal recommendation to users is to always accept answer that has helped solve their problem so that other users can quickly find a solved problem. I can add an answer if you desire.